# Role provider and Role management

Tags: asp.net, caching, roles

> When the CacheRolesInCookie property is set to true in the Web.config file, role information for each user is stored in a cookie. When role management checks to see whether a user is in a particular role, the roles cookie is checked before the role provider is called to check the list of roles at the data source. The cookie is dynamically updated to cache the most recently validated role names.

a) As far as I understand the above text, even though role management checks the roles cookie, role provider still checks the list of roles at the data source?

b) Above text talks about role management, which is invoked before role provider is called.  What class acts as a role management?

thanx

**EDIT:**

> As far as I understand it, the information cached within the cookie includes all available roles, not just the ones your user is a member of. So I do not believe that the database would be hit each and every time.

From same site as the quote from my previous post:

> **Roles.CacheRolesInCookie Property Value**
>
> true if the current user's roles are cached in a cookie; otherwise, false. The default is true.

This suggests that only roles for current user are stored in a cookie. Besides, if all roles where stored in a cookie, then role manager would still have to check the DB to see which of the roles current user is member of?!

> Role management is handled by the System.Web.Security.Roles class.

I thought the text used the term `role management` to refer to class/module that calls the methods of System.Web.Security.Roles, which in turn check whether user is a member of particular role?

Comment: The best way to answer your question is to test: fire up a SQL trace, and test under what conditions the database gets a hit. You can use the Roles class to perform all role management - from adding users to a role, to checking if a role exists.

Answer (score 1):

Role management is handled by the *System.Web.Security.Roles* class. As far as I understand it, the information cached within the cookie includes all *available* roles, not just the ones your user is a member of. So I do not believe that the database would be hit each and every time.

If you were to change the list of available roles (i.e. by creating a new role), then the provider would invalidate the cache in the cookie on the next round trip.

//Richard.